# Inline colorbox group from multiple links

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to run a colorbox group from a click event on a div (which also contains a child anchor link) to show hidden inline content. I've got it working correctly on the anchor link inside the div but I'm not sure how to have colorbox run from this anchor link AND/OR the click on the parent div. Heres my jquery.

```
$(".staffMemberWrap").click(function() {
    $(".inline").colorbox ({
        inline:true, 
        width:"510", 
        rel:'group1', 
        href: anchorHref, 
        current: "{current} of {total}"
    });
    var anchorHref = $(this).inline.find('a').attr('href');
});
```

My div and child anchor code looks like this

```
<div id="staff1" class="staffMemberWrap">
    <div class="staffMemberName"><a class='inline' href="#inline_content" rel="group1"><strong>Name Here</strong></a></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:

```
$(function(){

  $(".staffMemberName, .staffMemberName.a").click(function(e){
     colorBoxMe($(this));
  });

 });

function colorBoxMe($element){
   $element.colorbox ({
    inline:true, 
    width:"510", 
    rel:'group1', 
    href: $(this).attr('href'), 
    current: "{current} of {total}"
  });  
}
```

I think I have it more to what you want here. ColorBox doesn't really need to be called each click, but this should be a start. Some reading of colorbox documentation might help clean it up for you.

[Example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/apunen/4/edit).

Comment: Thanks agrothe, I tried that but now colorbox won't run on the anchor links or the divs.

Comment: FYI, just updated code, to remove the errant 'inline' jquery piece. I can't find a CDN link to colorbox or I would do a fiddle for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response agrothe, I tried that too but now I have an incorrect number of elements in the group. Your example fiddle shows the same problem. i.e. 1 of 2.

Comment: @user2496926 right. I updated the example and answer. without the styles its a bit hard to see if the right div is populating the color box, but the behavior seems right now.

Comment: Thanks agrothe, its almost there. The colorbox is not populating the correct divs and the number of elements in the group in incrementing on the click of each. i.e. When you first load and click the box you don't see '1 of 2'. I've added the hidden items to this link with my original jquery code to show it working on the anchors only. http://jsbin.com/iputib/1/

Comment: @user2496926 This seems to work except the '1 of 2' is not visible. It is on the page though, as you can see by inspecting the html. Not sure if it works better on your site? http://jsbin.com/iputib/4/edit